# How to avoid running code when a script is imported as a package?

Tags: packages, scripting

In Python, the boilerplate line `if __name__ == "__main__":` defines a code block that should be executed when the code is run as a script, but not when imported as a module.

Is there a way to do this using Mathematica's `.wls` scripts?

To clarify, I want to designate part of my code to be run only when the script is run in an interactive session or from the command line (e.g. using `wolframscript`), but not when the code is imported into another notebook/script using `Get` or similar.

Comment: you could check if [`$ScriptCommandLine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ScriptCommandLine.html) is `{}`

Comment: `$ScriptCommandLine == {}` is the same as `$Notebooks`, as far as I can tell. It tells me if I'm running code from a front end (vs. a command line), not whether I'm running code directly from a notebook/script (vs. importing it). I added some clarification to the question.

Comment: Make sure those cells you don't want evaluated when the package loads do not have the property `Initialization Cell`

Comment: $EvaluationEnvironment would be the solution but I do not know if it wors for scrips, it was quite buggy.

Comment: Instead of relying on which mode the file is read via, why not just have the `main[]` function only evaluate if a certain global flag is set.  When the file is read, if ```Global`$EvaluateFlag``` is not `True`, you don't run the `main[]` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use `$EvaluationEnvironment` to check notebooks vs. Scripts.

If you are trying to check against whether it is the main file or not `$Input` may be useful. It should be set when `Get`-ing a file or similar. So the check `If[$Input==="", ...]` may work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I think `$Input` is the best solution.

Comment: Warning: This works when running interactively, or when using `wolframscript -file`, or using `./script.wls` with the shebang. But `wolframscript -script script.wls` sets the value of `$Input` to the path of the script.

Answer (score 4):

This works on my Windows machine (not sure how well it translates to Mac and Linux yet):

Place this in a file called `test.wls`:

```
checks = { $Notebooks, Length[$CommandLine]===1, MemberQ[$CommandLine,"-wlbanner"], MemberQ[$CommandLine,"-noicon"] };
Print @ Switch[
 checks,
 {True,False,False,True}, "Running in notebook interface",
 {False,True,False,False}, "Running in wolfram.exe",
 {False,False,True,False}, "Running in wolframscript.exe",
 {False,False,False,False}, "Running in test.wls"
];
```

Then run this file in different modes. First as a script:

```
C:\Users\arnoudb.WRI>test.wls
Running in test.wls
```

Then using `wolframscript.exe`:

```
C:\Users\arnoudb.WRI>wolframscript
Wolfram Language 11.3.0 Engine for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2018 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= Get["test.wls"]
Running in wolframscript.exe
```

Then using `wolfram.exe`:

```
C:\Users\arnoudb.WRI>"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.3\wolfram.exe"
Mathematica 11.3.0 Kernel for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2018 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= Get["test.wls"]
Running in wolfram.exe
```

And finally from a notebook interface:

```
Get["C:\\Users\\arnoudb.WRI\\test.wls"]

Running in notebook interface
```

Probably needs some work to get this more solid.

Comment: These differentiate between the different environments that run Mathematica code, but not between the "main" file and imported modules, as the Python code does. Running `wolframscript -file test.wls` will yield the same result as `wolframscript -run "Get[\"test.wls\"]"`. It may be that what I'm asking for isn't possible in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

The way that works is that when Python runs a source file as the main program, it first sets the variable `__name__` to `"__main__"` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do#419185)). As far as I know, Mathematica does no such thing for you, so unless you want to require every source file to include code to replicate that behavior, the closest I can think of is to have the script check if it is being evaluated as part of a `Get` or `Needs` expression. Something like:

```
If[
    MatchQ[Stack[], {___, Get|Needs, If, MatchQ}],
    Print["this will evaluate if being imported by Get or Needs"],
    Print["this will evaluate otherwise"]
]
```

That being said, I wouldn't really recommend writing code like this and would rethink if this behavior is really necessary.